# autoscroll (like movie credits) but the user can takeover by simply scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, autoscroll

I am looking into creating a website which will serve as a a digital leaflet for a musical theatre. The idea is to have an autoscrolling credits list as landingpage. I've looked at examples on codepen to see how this effect is been achieved. But I would also like the user to interact and scroll themselves if they want to. When they stop scrolling the credits will turn back to autoscroll. I didn't find any example who tackles this issue. Does someone of you know a script (JS, or plain css…) that can help me with this?

Comment: This website is to help you with a code, not code it for you. Show us what you got so far, than someone might be able guide you. I'm surprised this question was up for an hour and not a single downvote yet...downvoters are slacking today...

Comment: Oh i'm really sorry about giving that impression. Didn't mean to ask for ready made code. I just wanted to have some advice on where to look for. But i'll definitely watch my language next time.

Comment: Make sure you stop autoscrolling when the user mouses over the credits. Otherwise, when the user manually scrolls to a particular spot, it will autoscroll out of view, which would be a poor UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your auto scroll routine before changing position check if previous position is the same as current scrolling position, if it's not - the user scrolled it:

```js
let el = document.documentElement,
    footer = document.getElementById("status").querySelectorAll("td"),
    scroll_position = 0,
    scroll_speed = 0,
    scroll_delta = 1.12,
    scroller,
    status = "stopped";

el.addEventListener("click", scroll);

info();

function scroll(e)
{
  if (e.type == "click")
  {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(scroller);
    scroll_position = el.scrollTop; //make sure we start from current position
    scroll_speed++; //increase speed with each click
    info("auto scroll");
  }
  //if previous position is different, this means user scrolled
  if (scroll_position != el.scrollTop)
  {
    scroll_speed = 0;
    info("stopped by user");
    return;
  }

  el.scrollTop += scroll_delta * scroll_speed; //scroll to new position
  scroll_position = el.scrollTop; //get the current position

  //loop only if we didn't reach the bottom
  if (el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop - el.clientHeight > 0)
  {
    scroller = window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll); //loop
  }
  else
  {
    el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight; //make sure it's all the way to the bottom
    scroll_speed = 0;
    info("auto stopped");
  }
}

function info(s)
{
  if (typeof s === "string")
    status = s;

  footer[1].textContent = el.scrollTop;
  footer[3].textContent = scroll_speed;
  footer[5].textContent = status;

}

//generate html demo sections
for(let i = 2, section = document.createElement("section"); i < 6; i++)
{
  section = section.cloneNode(false);
  section.textContent = "Section " + i;
  document.body.appendChild(section);
}

//register scroll listener for displaying info
window.addEventListener("scroll", info);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body
{
  font-family: "Roboto", Arial;
  user-select: none;
}

section
{
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

section:nth-child(even)
{
  background: #0b0d19;
}

section:nth-child(odd)
{
  background: #131524;
}

#status
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

#status td:first-of-type
{
  text-align: end;
  padding-right: 0.4em;
}
#status td:last-of-type
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>
  Click to start Scrolling
</section>

<table id="status">
  <tr><td>position:</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>speed:</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>status:</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer went beyond my expectations! Forever gratefull for the help, with some tweaks this will definitely do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to set up a requestAnimationFrame() function and increment the value accordingly, then set the scroll position to it.
Then add the wheel event to detect when a user scrolls (don't use the 'scroll' event though, it already gets called when you change the scrollTop value of the body), also don't forget to cancel the requestAnimationFrame() function. The code would look something like this:

```
let body = document.body,
  starter = document.querySelector("h1"),
  scroll_counter = 0,
  scrolled,
  auto_scroll_kicked = false;

starter.addEventListener("click", start_scrolling);

function start_scrolling() {
  auto_scroll_kicked = true;
  body.offsetHeight > scroll_counter
    ? (scroll_counter += 1.12)
    : (scroll_counter = body.offsetHeight);
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = scroll_counter;
  scroller = window.requestAnimationFrame(start_scrolling);

  if (scroll_counter >= body.offsetHeight) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(scroller);
  }
}
window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  if (auto_scroll_kicked) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(scroller);
    scroll_counter = 0;
  }
});
```

Play with the codepen if you'd like:
https://codepen.io/SaltyMedStudent/pen/QWqVwaR?editors=0010

There are many options to use: easing functions and etc, but hope this will suffice for now.